# how to show previous div of clicked div in angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i have a html like this

```
  <div  class="main" ng-controller="firstcontroller">
       <div class="submain">
           <div class="first" ng-show="display">displayed</div>
           <div class="second" my-directive>click</div>
       </div>
       <div class="submain">
           <div class="first" ng-show="display">displayed</div>
           <div class="second" my-directive>click</div>
       </div>
       <div class="submain">
           <div class="first" ng-show="display">displayed</div>
           <div class="second" my-directive>click</div>
       </div>
 </div>
```

I have controller like this

```
     app.controller('firstcontroller',function($scope)
     {
         $scope.display=false;

     });
```

my directive coding like this

```
 app.directive('myDirective',function(scope, element, attrs)
 {
    return function()
    {
        element.bind('click',function()
       {
             element.prev().show();
            //alert(element.prev().attr('class'));

        //   element.parent().find('.main').append('<div>Some text</div>')
       });


    }

 });
```

here initially div will be hidden if div has class name fist , only div having class name second  will be displayed . so when we click on click div we have to show only previous div of that clicked div..... how to show previous div of clicked div in angular.js ?

Answer (score 2):

I get the feeling that the question is missing information. E.g. are the `.submain` divs hardcoded, or created by iteration?

If however this is indeed the case, the directive is redundant. Change the HTML as:

```
<div  class="main" ng-controller="firstcontroller">
   <div class="submain">
       <div class="first" ng-show="display[0]">displayed</div>
       <div class="second" ng-click="display[0] = !display[0]">click</div>
   </div>
   <div class="submain">
       <div class="first" ng-show="display[1]">displayed</div>
       <div class="second" ng-click="display[1] = !display[1]">click</div>
   </div>
   <div class="submain">
       <div class="first" ng-show="display[2]">displayed</div>
       <div class="second" ng-click="display[2] = !display[2]">click</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And the controller:

```
 app.controller('firstcontroller',function($scope) {
     $scope.display=[false, false, false];
 });
```

Comment: You should adapt the array of booleans in the controller then.